# Firebase dynamic links show warning about non-existing apps

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

We're having a strange problem that so far seems harmless but I prefer not to ignore just in case in bites us later.

We're creating dynamic links using the REST API(but the warnings also appear in the debug console).

We get warnings like this:

```
warningCode "UNRECOGNIZED_PARAM"
warningMessage  "Android app com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#android-sha256-absent]"
```

The issue is not that SHA256 thing, but the fact that the app 'com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm' (the result of a quick copy/paste when we first started) hasn't existed in the firebase project for months. It doesn't appear in the console at all, and I can't find any reference to it in the project code.

So where are the mobile apps stored? Is there a way for us to do clean up?