# Firebase Dynamic Links shows Warning for deleted and non existing Apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have finished set up Firebase Dynamic Links resolved all errors in Debug (`?d=1`). But there is one warning I can not resolve.

> ```
> The dynamic link has 1 warning(s)
> Android app 'my.old_and_deleted.package_name' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app. Learn more.
> ```

Now I can not resolve the error because it is a Firebase mistake. The Android App with that package name was deleted a while ago. No traces of the app in Firebase Console, not even in `google-services.json`. Now whenever I try to debug the dynamic Link I get the same error.

Someone asked the resembling question 2 years ago, but it was not answered.

> [Firebase dynamic links show warning about non-existing apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392514/firebase-dynamic-links-show-warning-about-non-existing-apps)

But could not get an answer. How can I remove the error/warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I filed the issue as a bug to Firebase Support and Today they have responded with the Solution to the Problem. I have decided I will post the Answer here:

> This issue happens when you add an app to your Firebase project, an OAuth client ID is automatically created for it in the associated Google Cloud project. However, deleting the app doesn't remove these client IDs, which can cause issues for the FDL (Firebase Dynamic Links ).

> To resolve this issue, you have to either change the bundle ID for these client IDs or remove them entirely by following the below steps:

1. Access the project on the Cloud console [(console.cloud.google.com)](http://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. Go to `APIs and Services > Credentials`
3. Identify the client ID with the conflicting bundle ID in your OAuth 2.0 Client IDs in the name (ex: [Android/iOS] client for <`package name/bundleID`> (auto created by Google Service)
4. Edit the package name/bundle ID and save changes or delete the OAuth client ID

For my case step 4 was just deleting the package name.

`CREDIT: FIREBASE SUPPORT TEAM.`